# Partition Removal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

**Background:**

I have a very persistent malware problem I am unable to remove, even with a full disk *disk wipe and re-install.  I believe the malware is either residing in an inconspicuous location on my storage drive or in the firmware on my motherboard.

```
 *Disk wipe includes removing all partitions and performing a low level format with programs such as Gnome Disks, GParted, Parted, FDisk, SFDisk, FDisk (Dos version), Diskpart (Win 10), ActiveKilldisk, DBAN, Partition Magic, Partition Mini-Tool, etc.
```

**Pre-Actions:**

After booting to live Ubuntu USB, I opened the "Gnome Disks" program and deleted all the partitions on the disk in question, then rebooted.

**Actions:**

After I use the `fdisk -l` command from a live Ubuntu USB to list the partitions on my storage drive, I get the output listed below.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 974E0A83-A8F5-426A-9C6F-3875011C574E

Device     Start   End Sectors Size Type
/dev/sda1     34 32767   32734  16M Microsoft reserved

*Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.*
```

After deleting partition one and issuing a print command, I get the following message.

```
Command (m for help): d

Selected partition 1
Partition 1 has been deleted.

Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 974E0A83-A8F5-426A-9C6F-3875011C574E

Command (m for help): d

*No partition is defined yet!
Could not delete partition 93960418819865*

Command (m for help):
```

**Questions:**

Primary:

Can someone please explain why and how to correct the messages "Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary" and "Could not delete partition 93960418819865"?  According to the output, I just deleted all partitions, so partition 93960418819865 shouldn't exist.

Secondary:

What is partition 93960418819865?

Comment: It appears you found a bug in `fdisk`. It may be using an uninitialized variable. // Please provide the output of `fdisk -v`.

Comment: Well nevermind, it *is* use of an uninitialized `size_t`. As such, you may safely ignore the large number.

Comment: Instead of mercilessly re-wiping the disk, change for another disk and see if the malware returns. This said, what makes you think you have a malware looming (and not a mere software bug/hardware problem)? Did anyone else confirm this?

Comment: I have replaced, storage devices, motherboards, networking equipment and even complete computers, only to the new equipment re-infected.  I have worked extensively with Malwarebytes, and other big named anti-malware companies over the course of 18 months but get the same result of being told I need someone that has can be physically present to analyze the issue.

Comment: cont.
My issue is that I live in a relatively urban location, where  there really isn't anyone with the technical background to diagnose and solve this problem.  The symptoms are analogous with a complicated rootkit or hyper-visor rootkit and show other indications of being a firmware virus in the ACPI.

Comment: I have also had problems with the presence of a hacker but this has subsided for now.  I would simply replace all of my hardware but I am not convinced that this would eliminate the problem as I do not know where it is stemming from and I do not have the cash to take that kind of gamble.

Comment: I have arrived to the conclusion that the malware is in one of three location, one: being in an obscure location on the storage drive (if possilble), two: in the firmware on the mother board or other attached hardware, which is not assesible to consumer and is capable of being remotely accessed (highly doubtful if even possible), three: in the firmware of a networking component such as a router or modem (possible) or four: in the firmware of one of my televisions or stereo receivers (highly unlikely).

Comment: So, now that we dealt with the `fdisk` strangeness, you should probably explain ([in your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1342957/edit)!) what makes you think you have a virus at all. All *I* see is a regular partition.

Comment: I was trying to avoid getting into this topic because of how this system is structured for help and the kind of questions that are acceptable to ask, so they are not open ended and helpful to all who read the thread.  Also, it isn't so easy to explain what is I've experienced in 18 months in just a few words on a short, direct question and answer help forum but I will try non-the-less.

Comment: The main symptoms I am experiencing are shared across 7 PCs and four smart phones.  I see symptoms when using Windows (primarily), Linux and also have issues with Android.  The symptoms I experience are reduced performance, high system resource consumption, random file and part ion changes, altered permissions on files and folders, BSODs, altered MBR’s, PBR and VBR’s, virtual machine creation, programs not running as expected (mainly anti-malware

Comment: programs), high networking traffic/data usage, increased space usage on local storage devices, net work changes and share folder creation, scan detection with multiple AV programs, spoofed web pages, what seems to be a presence of a hacker and remote connection, identity theft and online account hijacking.  I’m sure I could think of and list more but this should give you an idea.

Comment: Please see the log files I've uploaded to my one drive account, in particular the kernel log; this may give some indication of what is going on but I am not sure myself as I am not a professional.  Also, I have a screen shot from another log file that was taken earlier, that mentions specter meltdown v1, v2....again not sure the significance behind the information.  https://1drv.ms/f/s!AnlUmjx8JjLGrzfpqGK6hIVnAtI4

Comment: Suspecting a hacker and the very real possibility of malware saved to your backups, your only real path to being clean is to get all new hardware, including drives, and to NOT restore from backups, but to manually re-create any required data. Once a malicious actor is in as deep as it appears they may be in this case, there is no way to eradicate with certainty without starting completely over from scratch.

Comment: Without knowing where the vulnerability which is allowing access is,  there wouldn't be any guarantee that replacing equipment would solve my problem correct?.  Is there another way of determining how access is being gained and secure that instead?  Buying all new equipment would set me back nearly $5,000-$7,000 and I do not have that option right now.  On a side not, I get the feeling that this malware is being dumped on my machines from a remote server and if I could prevent the connection from ever taking place, that would eradicate my problem.

Comment: To mention one other point that may be useful, I have seen warnings from the manufactures included software for my SSD, that using raw disk space will prematurely cause drive failure; this lead to a suspicion of mine that there is a call to a specific location on my storage drives for regeneration but that location would have to either be encrypted or hidden.  Using a hex editor program I have also seen information lying on the outside of the disc "boundary", leaving the computer confused or blind to that information but I don't know how to access that information to remove it if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you just zero out your disk: Assuming the disk in question is /dev/sda, you would use `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M` to start this process, which I estimate to take something like 3 hours. Not only will this remove the boot sector and all partitions and file systems, it even will overwrite all instances of whatever is on this disk short of forensic reconstruction.

A short version of `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M count=10240` will do this to just the first 10 GB of the disk, which should be more than enough and take only 2 minutes or so.

After this procedure reboot and enjoy.

**Caveat:**

It is quite likely, that your persisctance problem with the malware stems from infected backups or EFI - no amount of disk wiping can cure that.

Comment: I have done what you have suggested (several times) but I still have the malware return.  I have also tried using the hdparm --dco-restore command but I get the following output.  Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: **With output this time

root@ubuntu:~# hdparm --yes-i-know-what-i-am-doing --dco-restore /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 issuing DCO restore command
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 00 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
root@ubuntu:~#

Comment: As I said in the caveat: If your malware still returns, it might not come from the disk but from the EFI or from restoring an infected backup.